# Creating Custom Jquery Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/6j4cT/3/

Sorry for not pasting the code as there is too much to add into this post.

Firstly the JQuery I have so far is not selecting first LI within the "news-items" and adding the class "active".

Also, if anyone would like to rewrite my code to a cleaner format you are welcome to do so.

Many thanks!

Comment: I would suggest rewriting your code to a cleaner format. Also, you should try to post some of this cleaner code in your question so we can help you. Eliminate the parts that aren't causing the problem and post the rest.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff, clearly the OP did not express that sentence as it was meant to be interpreted.

Comment: when you define menu, it is grabbing all of the li elements. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ThinkingStiff I would if I could... my jquery skills aren't that good - if they were I wouldn't be here.

Comment: @JordyVialoux Sorry that was just me being funny trying to make a point. On StackOverflow we usually help with specific problems you're having, not code rewrites. Code rewriting questions work better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TroyCosentino Yes I want to grab all li elements and I will only "show" 4 using css.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Haha that's cool - I'm not exactly after a code rewrite - the main purpose for the post is to help with the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give the class name `active` to the first `li` element:

```html
<ul id="news-items">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Node 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Node 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Reference: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6j4cT/10/)

---

Status Update: [**jsFiddle Rev 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/6j4cT/11/)

You can also add the class using jQuery as such:

```js
var periodToChangeSlide = 5000;
var pp_slideshow = undefined;
var currentPage = 0;
$('#news-items li:first').addClass('active');
```

---

Re-Revised via Message Request: [**jsFiddle Rev 4**](http://jsfiddle.net/6j4cT/14/)

```js
var periodToChangeSlide = 5000;
var pp_slideshow = undefined;
var currentPage = 0;
$('#news-feature-img-wrap li').css('display','list-item').slice(1).css('display','none');
$('#news-items li:first').addClass('active');
```

The new addition, per your message comments, will set `display:list-item` for only the first item while setting `display:none` for the remainder of the items since that has been sliced off via jQuery `.slice()` method.

Comment: I would if I could. The nav is populated through a CMS called "umbraco" so the "news-items" are populated dynamically. I am using xslt to populate this section using a xsl:for-each so I cannot use this solution. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @attronics - the answer is perfect just one little thing to add. Can you please show or add in the jsfiddle document to make the LI's display: none; within "news-feature-img-wrap" except for the first item? onload all items are displaying and then they hide.

Comment: Open chrome and run the jsfiddle - inspect the li element onload and you will see that they are all displaying and then the timer kicks in to THEN hide the remaining list items.

Comment: @attronics here is a screeny for you - click on the image for a larger view. This illustrates the onload list items not being hidden. http://postimage.org/image/p6lok3uit/

Answer (score 1):

Back in SO after few days now `:)` Solution: **Working demo** - http://jsfiddle.net/qJea8/ or http://jsfiddle.net/qJea8/show

Behaviour now when you click on `Node 1` it will go to first slide and so on for the next one.

Culprit was: `var index = $(this).parent().index();` Change to `var index = $(this).index();` because parent will return same index all the time.

Rest I hope it helps the cause. `:)`

**Code**

```
// News Article Slideshow
var periodToChangeSlide = 5000;
var pp_slideshow = undefined;
var currentPage = 0;
$("#news-feature-wrap #news-items li").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

    var index = $(this).index();
    var toShow = $("#news-feature-wrap #news-feature-img-wrap li").eq(index);
    toShow.show();
    toShow.siblings().hide();
    currentPage = index;
    $.stopSlideshow();
});

$.startSlideshow = function() {
    if (typeof pp_slideshow == 'undefined') {
        pp_slideshow = setInterval($.startSlideshow, periodToChangeSlide);
    } else {
        $.changePage();
    }
}

$.stopSlideshow = function() {
    clearInterval(pp_slideshow);
    pp_slideshow = undefined;
}
$.changePage = function() {
    var numSlides = $('#news-feature-wrap #news-feature-img-wrap li').length;
    currentPage = (currentPage + 1) % numSlides;
    var menu = $('#news-feature-wrap #news-items li').eq(currentPage);
    menu.addClass('active');
    menu.siblings().removeClass('active');

    var toShow = $("#news-feature-wrap #news-feature-img-wrap li").eq(currentPage);
    toShow.show();
    toShow.siblings().hide();
}

$.startSlideshow();​
```

**Working image**

[image]

Comment: Hey - thanks for this! The behaviour cannot change as when a user clicks on the news-item it will take them to the detail page. The news-items list needs to cycle through on a timer of 5000.

Comment: @JordyVialoux cool `:)` lol lemme know what sort of behaviour you are aiming for if it ain't make any sense I will remove the post `B-)`

Comment: What I'm after is for the slider on load to have the first li within "news-items" list to have class "active" added and on a 5000 timer for each list item in news-items to cycle. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @JordyVialoux I reckon you got your answer now, `:)` not bothering to recheck stuff now, see you in another question `:P`